# How to define path with wildcard properties/keys in JSON schema

Tags: json, yaml, wildcard, jsonschema, key-value

I have YAML files that look like this...

```
material: iron_leggings
displayName: "Plated Leggings"
rare:
  effects:
    entry0:
      slot: legs
      name: life_steal
```

And I want to validate (using a JSON schema) that the *slot* property contains *legs* if the *materials* property contains the word *leggings*.

**Problem:**
The *rare* key can change name [common, uncommon, rare] and the *entry0* property can also take any name. I want a schema that can path into:
**[common, uncommon, rare] -> effects -> (wildcard) -> slot**

This is part of the schema I have so far, but I don't want to copy it for all combinations of possible keys:

```
      "if": { "properties": { "material": { "pattern": "(leggings)" } } },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "rare": {
            "properties": {
              "effects": {
                "properties": {
                  "entry0": { "properties": { "slot": { "pattern": "legs" } } } } } } } } } }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `additionalProperties` in place of `properties` with a name.

```
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "material": {
        "pattern": "(leggings)"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "rare": {
        "properties": {
          "effects": {
            "additionalProperties": {       // <- this
              "properties": {
                "slot": {
                  "pattern": "legs"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```